# Variabes in Drools

Tags: drools

Unable to use the variable in condition of rule 2 where the value of same variable is set in rule 1 which fires before the execution of rule 2. Below is the rules

```
rule "Rule1"
no-loop true
lock-on-active true
salience 1000
    when 
        $ExeMode: Module( event.type in ("summer", "spring"))
    then
        $ExeMode.getEvent().setStatus("Available");
        System.out.println($ExeMode.getEvent().getStatus());
        update($ExeMode);


rule "Rule2"
no-loop true
lock-on-active true
salience 999
    when 
        $Mod: Module( event.status in ("Available", "NotAvailable"))
    then
        $Mod.getEvent().setResult("Booked");
```

Status variable is set in rule1 and able to print the value in it.

when i use the same variable as condition in rule2. then rule2 is not firing.
please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `lock-on-active` attribute in your rules, meaning that no new activation will be triggered from the RHS of your rules.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Tried without lock-on-active for both the rules.  still the conditioni is not satisfing. if write the condition in "then" part instead of else then its working. EX: updated rule 2 :rule "Rule2"
no-loop true
salience 999
 when 
  $Mod: Module( )
 then
  if($Mod.getEvent.getStatus()== "Available"){
   System.out.println("TEST");
  }
  $Mod.getEvent().setResult("Booked");